# Rails gem path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a rails app where I was installing gems and it worked fine.
Now, I do not knwow what I did, when I add a gem in the Gemfile and run bundle install, the app crashes with the Gem not found error (example.: "We're sorry, but something went wrong. ... Could not find gmaps4rails-2.1.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)...").

I tried the command:
which gem gmaps4rails
output: /usr/bin/gem

Passenger error shows:
    System Information

```
Ruby interpreter command
/home/webmaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/ruby

User and groups
uid=1001(webmaster) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),27(sudo),110(lxd)

Environment variables

APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
LANG = C
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
PWD = /var/www/maus_view
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.1.5
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXIfqFGX
USER = webmaster
LOGNAME = webmaster
SHELL = 
HOME = /home/webmaster
IN_PASSENGER = 1
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
RAILS_ENV = development
RACK_ENV = development
WSGI_ENV = development
NODE_ENV = development
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = development
BUNDLER_ORIG_PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
GEM_PATH = /home/webmaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0:/home/webmaster/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
GEM_HOME = /home/webmaster/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
```

I've read a lot of stackoverflow's post but I'm not able to debug and find a solution to this issue.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you

--- EDIT ---

This is my **Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise'
#gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile content, it might help?

Comment: have you tried running  'gem install gmaps4rails'

Answer (score 2):

for some gems you need to install them through command line instead of just 'bundle installing' them. 
So try running:

`gem install gmaps4rails`

And go to you projects directory and hit `bundle install`

Hope it helps!

Comment: From inside the root of my app, I've tried 
    "gem install gmaps4rails" but I've got an error: 
"ERROR: While executing gem ...  (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.3.8/gems/gmaps4rails-2.1.2/.gitignore"

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu OS? If try running sudo command and let me know

Comment: Yes @Aashish, I'm on Ubuntu server 16.04.


sudo gem install gmaps4rails
worked

then I hit bundle install

but:
bundle show gmaps4rails
outputs: "Could not find gmaps4rails"

which gem gmaps4rails outputs: /usr/bin/gem

In the asset pipeline I put:
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google

The gem I think is not working as I get Sprockets::FileNotFound error: (couldn't find file 'gmaps/google' with type 'application/javascript')